# installing GNU MCU Eclipse failed in linux LMDE 3 (cindy)

Tags: eclipse, arm, gnu

I need to work with arm mcu (especially STM32 and Raspberry pi mcu), so I read this instruction :

[How to install the GNU MCU Eclipse plug-ins?](https://gnu-mcu-eclipse.github.io/plugins/install/#compatibility-issues)

So when I want to do the instruction:

> go to the Eclipse menu → Help → Eclipse Marketplace…, find GNU MCU
> Eclipse and install

I get this error:

[error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dNrG.png)

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: GNU MCU C/C++ Packs (Experimental) 2.2.2.201901011632 (ilg.gnumcueclipse.packs.feature.feature.group 2.2.2.201901011632)
  Software currently installed: Eclipse Platform 3.7.0.debbuild (org.eclipse.platform.ide 3.7.0.debbuild)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Eclipse Preferences Mechanism 3.4.0.v20110502 (org.eclipse.equinox.preferences 3.4.0.v20110502)
    Eclipse Preferences Mechanism 3.4.2.v20120111-2020 (org.eclipse.equinox.preferences 3.4.2.v20120111-2020)
    Eclipse Preferences Mechanism 3.5.0.dist (org.eclipse.equinox.preferences 3.5.0.dist)
    Eclipse Preferences Mechanism 3.6.1.v20160815-1406 (org.eclipse.equinox.preferences 3.6.1.v20160815-1406)
    Eclipse Preferences Mechanism 3.6.0.v20160120-1756 (org.eclipse.equinox.preferences 3.6.0.v20160120-1756)
    Eclipse Preferences Mechanism 3.4.1.R37x_v20110725 (org.eclipse.equinox.preferences 3.4.1.R37x_v20110725)
    Eclipse Preferences Mechanism 3.5.300.v20150408-1437 (org.eclipse.equinox.preferences 3.5.300.v20150408-1437)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: GNU MCU C/C++ Packs Core 2.2.2.201901011632 (ilg.gnumcueclipse.packs.core 2.2.2.201901011632)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.equinox.preferences 3.6.1
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: GNU MCU C/C++ Packs (Experimental) 2.2.2.201901011632 (ilg.gnumcueclipse.packs.feature.feature.group 2.2.2.201901011632)
    To: ilg.gnumcueclipse.packs.core [2.2.2.201901011632]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Equinox p2 Core Function 1.1.0.dist-829GFneFKlR6A96 (org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.feature.feature.group 1.1.0.dist-829GFneFKlR6A96)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.preferences [3.5.0.dist]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Equinox p2 Provisioning for IDEs. 2.2.0.dist-62DG8ltBaLdNsDyHEh7m9FbLOK8 (org.eclipse.equinox.p2.user.ui.feature.group 2.2.0.dist-62DG8ltBaLdNsDyHEh7m9FbLOK8)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.feature.feature.group [1.1.0.dist-829GFneFKlR6A96]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Platform 3.7.0.debbuild (org.eclipse.platform.ide 3.7.0.debbuild)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.user.ui.feature.group [2.2.0.dist-62DG8ltBaLdNsDyHEh7m9FbLOK8]
```

after that, So I test this :

```
name: GNU MCU Eclipse Plug-ins
URL: http://gnu-mcu-eclipse.netlify.com/v4-neon-updates/
```

So I got this error:

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: GNU MCU C/C++ Packs (Experimental) 2.2.2.201901011632 (ilg.gnumcueclipse.packs.feature.feature.group 2.2.2.201901011632)
  Software currently installed: Eclipse Platform 3.7.0.debbuild (org.eclipse.platform.ide 3.7.0.debbuild)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Eclipse Preferences Mechanism 3.4.0.v20110502 (org.eclipse.equinox.preferences 3.4.0.v20110502)
    Eclipse Preferences Mechanism 3.4.2.v20120111-2020 (org.eclipse.equinox.preferences 3.4.2.v20120111-2020)
    Eclipse Preferences Mechanism 3.5.0.dist (org.eclipse.equinox.preferences 3.5.0.dist)
    Eclipse Preferences Mechanism 3.6.1.v20160815-1406 (org.eclipse.equinox.preferences 3.6.1.v20160815-1406)
    Eclipse Preferences Mechanism 3.6.0.v20160120-1756 (org.eclipse.equinox.preferences 3.6.0.v20160120-1756)
    Eclipse Preferences Mechanism 3.4.1.R37x_v20110725 (org.eclipse.equinox.preferences 3.4.1.R37x_v20110725)
    Eclipse Preferences Mechanism 3.5.300.v20150408-1437 (org.eclipse.equinox.preferences 3.5.300.v20150408-1437)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: GNU MCU C/C++ Packs Core 2.2.2.201901011632 (ilg.gnumcueclipse.packs.core 2.2.2.201901011632)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.equinox.preferences 3.6.1
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: GNU MCU C/C++ Packs (Experimental) 2.2.2.201901011632 (ilg.gnumcueclipse.packs.feature.feature.group 2.2.2.201901011632)
    To: ilg.gnumcueclipse.packs.core [2.2.2.201901011632]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Equinox p2 Core Function 1.1.0.dist-829GFneFKlR6A96 (org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.feature.feature.group 1.1.0.dist-829GFneFKlR6A96)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.preferences [3.5.0.dist]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Equinox p2 Provisioning for IDEs. 2.2.0.dist-62DG8ltBaLdNsDyHEh7m9FbLOK8 (org.eclipse.equinox.p2.user.ui.feature.group 2.2.0.dist-62DG8ltBaLdNsDyHEh7m9FbLOK8)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.feature.feature.group [1.1.0.dist-829GFneFKlR6A96]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Platform 3.7.0.debbuild (org.eclipse.platform.ide 3.7.0.debbuild)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.user.ui.feature.group [2.2.0.dist-62DG8ltBaLdNsDyHEh7m9FbLOK8]
```

my laptop information is:

```
> so@notebook:~$ inxi -Fxz System:    Host: notebook Kernel:
> 4.9.0-8-amd64 x86_64 (64 bit gcc: 6.3.0)
>            Desktop: Cinnamon 3.8.8 (Gtk 3.22.11-1)
>            Distro: LMDE 3 (cindy) Machine:   Device: laptop System: LENOVO product: 80TV v: Lenovo ideapad 310-15IKB
>            Mobo: LENOVO model: Torronto 5C2 v: NO DPK
>            UEFI [Legacy]: LENOVO v: 3JCN26WW date: 03/07/2017 Battery    BAT0: charge: 23.8 Wh 99.5% condition: 23.9/30.0 Wh (80%)
>            
>            model: SMP L15M2PB3 status: N/A CPU:       Dual core Intel Core i7-7500U (-HT-MCP-) cache: 4096 KB
>            flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 11616
>            clock speeds: max: 3500 MHz 1: 748 MHz
>            2: 776 MHz 3: 738 MHz 4: 799 MHz Graphics:  Card-1: Intel Device 5916
>            bus-ID: 00:02.0
>            Card-2: NVIDIA GM108M [GeForce 920MX]
>            bus-ID: 03:00.0
>            Display Server: X.Org 1.19.2 drivers: modesetting,nouveau (unloaded: fbdev,vesa)
>            Resolution: 1920x1080@60.01hz
>            GLX Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics 620 (Kabylake GT2)
>            GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 13.0.6 Direct Rendering: Yes Audio:     Card Intel Device 9d71
>            driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:1f.3
>            Sound: ALSA v: k4.9.0-8-amd64 Network:   Card-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
>            driver: r8169 v: 2.3LK-NAPI port: 5000
>            bus-ID: 01:00.0
>            IF: enp1s0 state: down mac: <filter>
>            Card-2: Realtek RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
>            driver: rtl8821ae port: 4000
>            bus-ID: 02:00.0
>            IF: wlp2s0 state: up mac: <filter> Drives:    HDD Total Size: 2000.4GB (1.2% used)
>            ID-1: /dev/sda model: ST2000LM003_HN size: 2000.4GB
>            
>            ID-1: / size: 197G used: 12G (7%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda7
>            ID-2: /home size: 197G used: 11G (6%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda3 Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 37.0C mobo: N/A
>            Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A Info:      Processes: 250 Uptime: 5:34 Memory: 10178.4/11920.3MB
>            Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Gcc sys: 6.3.0
>            Client: Shell (bash 4.4.121) inxi: 2.3.5
```

why this happened?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have Eclipse 3.7 (Indigo) installed which is 7 years and 10 releases out of date.

As stated in the Compatibility Notes section on the page you linked at least Eclipse 4.6 is required - but you should probably use the current Eclipse.